# Deploying a SpringMVC project on Liferay . Error: ERROR [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:220]

Tags: java, spring, maven, liferay

LOG:

```
09:56:01,860 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:204] Processing HelloWorld-portlet-7.0.0.1.war
09:56:01,935 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][PortletAutoDeployListener:79] Copying portlets for C:\Users\anju\Downloads\liferay - server\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga3\deploy\HelloWorld-portlet-7.0.0.1.war
09:56:01,965 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][BaseDeployer:863] Deploying HelloWorld-portlet-7.0.0.1.war
09:56:01,965 ERROR [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:220] com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: HelloWorld-portlet-7.0.0.1.war does not support this version of Liferay
com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: HelloWorld-portlet-7.0.0.1.war does not support this version of Liferay
    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.autoDeploy(BaseDeployer.java:216)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.ThreadSafeAutoDeployer.autoDeploy(ThreadSafeAutoDeployer.java:36)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.PortletAutoDeployListener.deploy(PortletAutoDeployListener.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.deploy(AutoDeployDir.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.processFile(AutoDeployDir.java:211)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.scanDirectory(AutoDeployDir.java:275)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner.run(AutoDeployScanner.java:58)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: HelloWorld-portlet-7.0.0.1.war does not support this version of Liferay
    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployFile(BaseDeployer.java:902)
    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.autoDeploy(BaseDeployer.java:213)
    ... 6 more
09:56:01,966 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:224] Add HelloWorld-portlet-7.0.0.1.war to the blacklist
```

My liferay sdk : 6.2 and tomcat is 7.
I am trying to deploy the project in liferay. It's been a couple of days and I am unable to solve it.

My liferay plugin package:

```
name=HelloWorld
module-group-id=liferay
module-incremental-version=1
tags=
short-description=
long-description=
change-log=
page-url=http://www.liferay.com
author=Liferay, Inc.
licenses=LGPL
liferay-versions=7.0.0+
portal-dependency-jars=\
    commons-collections.jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Liferay SDK - at least the one that you started with, or the one that you copied `liferay-plugin-package.properties` from, is 7.0:
`liferay-versions=7.0.0+` declares that your portlet is compatible with 7.0.x and you seem to run Liferay 6.2

Make sure that you actually have a 6.2 SDK, change this declaration to a Liferay version that makes sense and you're set.